# Why does the javascript generated input isn't recognize by the javascript on change function?

Tags: javascript

This is the original input that has a class="time"

```
<input type="time" class="time" name="time_in[0]" id="time_in-0" />
<input type="time" class="time" name="time_out[0]" id="time_out-0" />
<input type="number" class="hours" readonly="" id="hours-0" />
<input type="number" class="total" readonly=""/>
```

And this is the javascript that I used to generate another input which also has a class time

```
$('.add-fields').on('click', add);

function add() {
  var array_no = parseInt($('#total_request').val());
  var new_input = $("<input type='time' class='time' name='time_in[" + array_no + "]' id='time_in-" + array_no + "' /><input type='time' class='time' name='time_out[" + array_no + "]' id='time_out-" + array_no + "' /><input type='number' class='hours' readonly='' id='hours-" + array_no + "' />");

  $('#new_request-' + increment_id).after(new_input);
}
```

This is the javascript that has on change function so the user can see the difference immediately after entering the time

```
$(".time").on("change", function() {
  var last_request_no = $('#total_request').val();
  var total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < last_request_no; i++) {
    var time_in = document.getElementById("time_in-" + i).value;
    var time_out = document.getElementById("time_out-" + i).value;
    var hours = parseInt($("#time_out-" + i).val()) - parseInt($("#time_in-" + i).val());

    $("#hours-" + i).val(parseInt($("#time_in-" + i).val()) + parseInt($("#time_out-" + i).val()))

    total += hours;
  }

  $('#total').val(total);
});
```

The problem is that when I enter the time on the generated input, it doesn't calculate the hours for that new input and the total, not until I edited the original input again then it would calculate everything correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the element didn't exist when you added the event listener.

You need to use [delegated event handler](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('change', '.time', function() {})
```

In your example jQuery adds the event handler to the elements that exists in the moment that you call .on(), any new element will not have the event handler

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling change function in document.ready() function. I guess it may solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry I'm just a newbie. I don't understand your answer

Comment: Please read this. You will get to know about document.ready function
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Does it mean I have to enclose all those codes inside `$(document).ready(function() {...});`?